# Wrong output with an addition table in php

Tags: php, debugging, html-table

I am having trouble creating an addition table for my php program. I created my multiplication table just fine (it creates the right output), but when I try and make an addition one the numbers arent inside the table and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. I will post what my output looks like when I create an addition table, and what it is supposed to look like and also the code that I have wrote. I feel like I am very close to completing this program, but right now I am stuck, thanks for the help in advance.

Here is the output that I am supposed to get for a 4x5 addition table.

```
0   1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4   5
2   3   4   5   6
3   4   5   6   7
4   5   6   7   8
5   6   7   8   9
```

Here is my output .

```
11112222333344445555
0   1   2   3   4
1
2
3
4
5
```

And here is my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Number of Rows:</td><td><input type="text" name="rows" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Number of Columns:</td><td><select name="columns">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="16">16</option>

</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Operation:</td><td><input type="radio" name="operation" value="multiplication" checked="yes">Multiplication</input><br/>
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="addition">Addition</input>
</td></tr>
</tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        //check to see if num of rows is numberic
    if ( isset($_POST["rows"]) && is_numeric($_POST["rows"])){
            //check to see if rows is a positive number
            if($_POST["rows"] > 0){

                    if(isset($_POST) && $_POST["operation"] == "multiplication"){
                            echo 'This is a '. $_POST["rows"] . ' x ' . $_POST["columns"] .'multiplication table';
                            echo "<table border=1";
                            echo'<tr>';
                    for($b = 0; $b <= $_POST["columns"];$b++){
                            echo '<th>'.$b.'</th>';}
                            echo '</tr>';
                    for($r = 1; $r <= $_POST["rows"]; $r++){
                            echo'<tr><th>'.$r.'</th>';

                            for($c = 1; $c <= $_POST["columns"]; $c++){
                                    echo '<td>' .$c*$r. '</td>';
                            }
                                            echo '</tr>';
                                    }
            echo "</table>";
            }

                    else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST["operation"] == "addition")
                    {
                            echo 'This is a '. $_POST["rows"]. ' x ' . $_POST["columns"] .' addition table';
                            echo "<table border = 1";
                            echo'<tr>';
                            for($a = 0; $a <= $_POST["columns"];$a++){
                                    echo '<th>'.$a.'</th>';}
                                    echo '</tr>';
                                    for($r = 1; $r <= $_POST["rows"]; $r++){
                                            echo '<tr><th>'.$r.'</th>';
                                            for($c = 1; $c <= $_POST["columns"]; $c++)
                                            {
                                                            echo '<td>' .$c+$r. '</td>';
                                            }
                                                    echo '</tr>';
            }
            echo "</table>";
            }

            else{
            echo 'Invalid rows columns parameters';
            exit();
            }
    }
    exit();
            }}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know if it's the issue, but you should use `echo '<td>' .($c+$r). '</td>';` - the concatenation operator has the same precedence as addition, so you might end up with something unexpected if you don't use the brackets

Comment: Let us know that given solution work or not. my one i checked and it does work. thats if you have any problem let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this.

**Note:** i only changed elseif statement which you used for additioin, so you can just copy and paste this as i changes nothing else.

so i divided the solution in three part and leave comment in bold for you to know which part i changed. thanks.

and post the comment what should you do next. In case it did not give you desired out come.

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Number of Rows:</td><td><input type="text" name="rows" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Number of Columns:</td><td><select name="columns">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="16">16</option>

</select>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>Operation:</td><td><input type="radio" name="operation" value="multiplication" checked="yes">Multiplication</input><br/>
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="addition">Addition</input>
</td></tr>
</tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

        //check to see if num of rows is numberic
    if ( isset($_POST["rows"]) && is_numeric($_POST["rows"])){
            //check to see if rows is a positive number
            if($_POST["rows"] > 0){

                    if(isset($_POST) && $_POST["operation"] == "multiplication"){
                            echo 'This is a '. $_POST["rows"] . ' x ' . $_POST["columns"] .'multiplication table';
                            echo "<table border=1";
                            echo'<tr>';
                    for($b = 0; $b <= $_POST["columns"];$b++){
                            echo '<th>'.$b.'</th>';}
                            echo '</tr>';
                    for($r = 1; $r <= $_POST["rows"]; $r++){
                            echo'<tr><th>'.$r.'</th>';

                           // for($c = 1; $c <= $_POST["columns"]; $c++){
                             //       echo '<td>' .$c*$r. '</td>';
                            //}
                                            echo '</tr>';
                                    }
            echo "</table>";
            }
```

**From here i change the code** In case it does not give you desired outcomes. you only have to change for loop part just change $_post['rows'] to $_post['columns'] in the first foreach loop. And in the second for loop chnage $_post['columns'] to $_post['rows']. Thanks

```
                    else if (isset($_POST) && $_POST["operation"] == "addition")
                    {
                            for($x=0; $x<$_POST['rows']+1; $x++)
{
    $i=0;
    $y= $i+$x;

    echo '<table border 1px solid black>';
    echo '<tr>';
    //$value[]=$x;
    echo '<td>'.$y.'</td>';
    for($value=1;$value<$_POST['columns']+1;$value++){
    $c=$y+$value;
   // $c=$y+$value;
        echo '<td>'.$c;

    echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

**My changes finished** Every thing is your code as it is.

```
echo "</table>";
                }

                else{
                echo 'Invalid rows columns parameters';
                exit();
                }
        }
        exit();
                }}

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a simple bug!

There is no error in your logic. The bug is in your echo statement for addition.

You just can't echo the addition directly. Use a bracket to surround them instead. It will work :-)

Like this;

```
   echo '<td>'.($c+$r).'</td>';
```

Please let us know if it solved your problem.

Thanks,